# Eclipse with Websphere 7.0.0.17: EJB project does not work with resources within the workspace, but works with resources on Server

Tags: eclipse, maven, ejb, websphere

My application works with Maven and has three modules:

- ear-module
- web-module
- ejb-module

EJB Version is 3.0.

Deployment works in both ways without error messages.

When I try to run the application with the Publishing settings for Websphere "Run server with resources on Server" it works fine.

When I try do the same with "Run server with resources within the workspace" and open the application in my Browser it fails with this error message:

> A resource reference binding could not be found for the following resource references [jdbc/nust], defined for the NustService component.

I am new in JEE5, but it seems to me that local the websphere cant find the ejb-jar.xml.

Here the pom for ejb modul:

```
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mycomp-nust-frontend-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>mycomp.app</groupId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mycomp-nust-frontend-svc</artifactId>
    <name>mycomp-nust-frontend-svc</name>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mycomp.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycomp-service-utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Add classpath container for Websphere Application Server 7 to the 
                Eclipse project. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v70/was.base.v7</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                    <projectNameTemplate>${project.name}</projectNameTemplate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any suggestions, more info needed?

thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your ejb-jar.xml. Remember, the ejb-jar.xml just declares references; the actual binding to a "real" resource is done by application server-specific files. In WebSphere's case, this file is ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, which should be located at the same directory as ejb-jar.xml. Do you happen to have that file there?

Comment: OK, so it means that, when RAD is set to use "Run with resources in workspace", this file can't be found.

Use WebSphere's "classloader viewer" to look at the list of directories associated with your application's classpath, at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation where my application's defined resources could not be found. The solution was to define the /WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_1348167502046" virtualHostName="default_host">
    <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#struts_blank"/>
    <resRefBindings jndiName="jms/MyConnectionFactory" xmi:id="cf">
        <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
    </resRefBindings>
    <messageDestinationRefBindings jndiName="jms/TopicSpace/Group/Test" xmi:id="myTopic">
        <bindingMessageDestinationRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
    </messageDestinationRefBindings>  
</com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

A senior developer in the team said that this should be a XML file but then that didn't work. I discovered this by exporting a deployed application from an IBM tutorial. Depending on your application you will have to change the above resource references.

Hope this helps